# cannot show the trace message in Output window when running unit test

Tags: trace

cannot show the trace message in Output window when running unit test

tried to use the output file in the property setting, but it does not work

Run a unit test method, it cannot show the trace log messages in Output window, but it can show in debug model.

```
  //[TestCategory("XXXNonCritical"), TestMethod]
  // public void XXXContainer
  // {
      //test code  
  //    Assert.IsTrue(metaSettingsData.Any());
  // }
```

expected to see the trace log messages in Output window

Comment: Have you tried to remove the `//` from the code?

Answer (score 0):

there is a link of Output in the unit test result where you can see the log.